# List of Acronyms without line spacing

Tags: acronyms

I use the `acronym`-package for my acronyms.

To create my List of Acronyms I have the following code in my main.tex:

```
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
...
\section*{List of Acronyms}
\input{../assets/acronyms}
```

and the acronyms.tex looks like:

```
\begin{acronym}
...
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}

  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
...
\end{acronym}
```

The result is this:
[image]

I really dislike the spaces between the acronyms and would prefer no line spacing, as in my List of Listings:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `acronym` environment is really just a `description` environment, one possibility is to specify the `itemsep` of the `acronym` environment:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{List of Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[JSONP]\itemsep0pt %change this amount as desired
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}
  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
\end{acronym}

\section{Foo}

\ac{JSON} and \ac{JSONP}.

\section{Bar}

\ac{REST}.

\end{document}
```

[image: acronym]

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a picture of what the output looks like :) Really adds to the quality of the answer, imo

Comment: Adding only `\itemsep` did not work but you need the `[JSONP]`-parameter as well. I did not understand why, but people following this solution should watch for that.

Comment: what exactly does the JSONP parameter stand for, here? Is it a coincidence that it matches one of the acronyms?

Comment: I figured out that the environment parameter (`[JSONP]`) is supposed to be the longest acronym used, as per the acronym pdf manual. It ensures they are aligned.

Answer (score 5):

The environment to patch is called `AC@deflist`, which we want to add `\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}` to.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\AC@deflist}
  {\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}}
  {\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section*{List of Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}[JSONP]
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}
  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
\end{acronym}

\section{Foo}

\ac{JSON} and \ac{JSONP}.

\section{Bar}

\ac{REST}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I needed the patch environment to get single spacing; just \itemsep did not work

Comment: @MilleCodex If you want to switch from double to single spacing, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Internally `acronym` uses `description`.  So you can either (1) redefine `acronym` using your own list structure, or (2) just before `acronym` redefine `description`.  Here is the second approach.  I've added `\itemsep0pt\parsep0pt` to the standard definition of `description`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\renewenvironment{description}
{\list{}{\labelwidth0pt\itemindent-\leftmargin
    \parsep0pt\itemsep0pt\let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}
  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE** When `perpage` option is used, the package adds an extra `\\`, probably a bug.  So in this case we need to redefine the way package prints the items as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printonlyused, withpage]{acronym}
\pagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
\def\AC@@acro#1[#2]#3{%
  \ifAC@nolist%
  \else%
  \ifAC@printonlyused%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname acused@#1\endcsname\AC@used%
       \item[\protect\AC@hypertarget{#1}{\aclabelfont{#2}}] #3%
          \ifAC@withpage%
            \expandafter\ifx\csname r@acro:#1\endcsname\relax%
               \PackageInfo{acronym}{%
                 Acronym #1 used in text but not spelled out in
                 full in text}%
            \else%
               \dotfill\pageref{acro:#1}% Sputious \\ deleted
            \fi
          \fi%
    \fi%
 \else%
    \item[\protect\AC@hypertarget{#1}{\aclabelfont{#2}}] #3%
 \fi%
 \fi%
 \begingroup
    \def\acroextra##1{}%
    \@bsphack
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
       {\string\newacro{#1}[\string\AC@hyperlink{#1}{#2}]{#3}}%
    \@esphack
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
We use \ac{JSON}, \ac{JSONP}, \ac{REST}.

\renewenvironment{description}
{\list{}{\labelwidth0pt\itemindent-\leftmargin
    \parsep0pt\itemsep0pt\let\makelabel\descriptionlabel}}
               {\endlist}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}

  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
\end{acronym}
\end{document}
 \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \begin{center}
    \input{tmp1.tex}
    \caption{Enter caption here}
    \label{Enter label here}
    \end{center}
    \end{figure}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already a few years old. However, I just had the same issue and found a simpler solution I want to share.

When defining the list of acronyms like in the question:

```
\begin{acronym}
...
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}

  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
...
\end{acronym}
```

Simply add the longest acronym in square brackets after the begin-statement like this:

```
\begin{acronym}[JSONP]
...
  \acro{JSON}{JavaScript Object Notation}
  \acro{JSONP}{JavaScript Object Notation with Padding}

  \acro{REST}{Representational State Transfer}
...
\end{acronym}
```

Yeah, that's all, `\itemsep0pt` is just necessary if you need custom line spacing.