# Tabulator between Acronym and full text

Tags: acronyms

Based on this post( [List of Acronyms without line spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364579/list-of-acronyms-without-line-spacing)), I want to create a list of appreciations. But the long text are not in the same column.

[image]

But this is not the result they have. I need the tabulator between the short and the longtext version (the red line).

[image]

This is my aacronym code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\AC@deflist}
  {\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}}
  {\addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\section*{Table of abbreciations}
\input{sources/abbreviations}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Use of \ac{saas} , \ac{yum}, \ac{jar} and \ac{ear} - \ac{LONGEXP}

\end{document}
```

with these abbreviations.tex

```
\begin{acronym}[d]
\acro{yum}[yum]{yellowdog updater modified}
\acro{ear}[EAR]{Enterprise Application Archive}
\acro{war}[WAR]{Web Application Resource}
\acro{jar}[JAR]{Java Archive}
\acro{saas}[SaaS]{Software as a Service}
\acro{LONGEXP}[LONGEXP]{A long acronym to make the point}
Markup Language}

\end{acronym}
```

The Output resulting Table of abbreviations is shown here:
[image]

But I need this result (Image edited with paint):
[image]

can another package interfere with the acronym-package?

Comment: Please add a minimum code from `\document{...`  to `\end{document}`. The class and the preamble are needed to answer your question.

Comment: Pleas include the  file `abbreviations`

Comment: Use `\begin{acronym}[LONGEXP]`

Comment: Can you write an answer with this solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{acronym}[LONGEXP]
    \acro{yum}[yum]{yellowdog updater modified}
    \acro{ear}[EAR]{Enterprise Application Archive}
    \acro{war}[WAR]{Web Application Resource}
    \acro{jar}[JAR]{Java Archive}
    \acro{saas}[SaaS]{Software as a Service}
    \acro{LONGEXP}[LONGEXP]{A long acronym to make the point}   
\end{acronym}
```

[image: a]